# Images won't display in Live Cycle Designer ES4

Tags: adobe, livecycle-designer

I am updating a form developed in Adobe Live Cycle Designer 8 with Live Cycle Designer ES4.When I try to imbed an image with a link to a new one it will not display in Design View and there is nothing visible in pdf view. There are some existing images which still display correctly. The images are imbedded.

Comment: Could you please provide more information. - Is it interactive form you are updating? - The image will not be displayed, but does it take place anyway? - Are you using an Image or Image Field? - Is your image file name consists only of lower case letter?

Comment: I've worked it out in the meantime thanks. The resolution of the .jpeg file was too high. I saved it as a .bmp file and it loaded successfully.